# What is the dimension of the largest preservable subspace for this linear evolution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, dynamical-systems

Let $G$ be an $n\times n$ complex matrix with block structure

$$G = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c|c}}
  {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
  {i{r_1}}&{}&{}&{} \\ 
  {}&{i{r_2}}&{}&{} \\ 
  {}&{}& \ddots &{} \\ 
  {}&{}&{}&{i{r_m}} 
\end{array}}& 0 \\ 
\hline
  0 & {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
  {{T_1}}&{}&{}&{} \\ 
  {}&{{T_2}}&{}&{} \\ 
  {}&{}& \ddots &{} \\ 
  {}&{}&{}&{{T_k}} 
\end{array}} 
\end{array}} \right)$$

with $r_1, r_2, \dots, r_m \in \mathbb{R}$ and $T_1, T_2, \dots, T_k$ being upper-triangular Jordan blocks of varying size for eigenvalues with strictly negative real part, e.g.

$${T_1} = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{\lambda _1}}&1 \\ 
  {}&{{\lambda _1}} 
\end{array}} \right), \;\Re\left(\lambda_1\right) < 0$$

Given a complex vector $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$, the time evolution

$$\dot{\vec{v}}=G\vec{v}$$

can be rewritten as

$$\dot{\vec v} = \underbrace {iP^\dagger D{P}}_{{\Phi _1}}\vec v + \underbrace {P^{\perp\dagger} H{P^\perp}}_{{\Phi _2}}\vec v$$

with $P$ being the top $m$ rows of $\mathbb{I}_{n\times n}$, $P^\perp = \mathbb{I}_{n\times n} - P$, $D$ being $m\times m$ real diagonal, and $H$ being Hurwitz.

The linear operator $\Phi_1$ can therefore be thought of as a length-preserving evolution of $\vec{v}$ projected onto $P^\dagger P$, and $\Phi_2$ as a strictly length-decreasing evolution of $\vec{v}$ projected into the complementary space.

Obviously the number of elements in $\vec{v}$ that will not decay to zero as $t\rightarrow\infty$ is given by $\operatorname{rank} P$, which is $m$. We denote the number of elements in $\vec{v}$ that *will* decay to zero while evolving under $G$ as $z\left(G\right)$, where it is readily seen that $z\left(G\right) = n-m$.

Now suppose we instead consider the time evolution

$$\dot{\vec{v}}=\left( G + G'\right)\vec{v}$$

where $G'$ is skew Hermitian.

It is readily seen that $G'$ can be chosen so that $n - m \leq z\left(G + G'\right) \leq n$.

It is my conjecture that $\forall\; m,k \geq 1$ there does not exist *any* skew Hermitian $G'$ such that $z\left(G + G'\right) < n - m$, however I'm unsure of how to prove or disprove this.

Any assistance or insights would be much appreciated.